# How do I query by the count of a property in nhibernate without using a detached criteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate-criteria

hey guys, I'm using NHibernate version 2.1.2.4000.

### The Entity

```
class bowl
{
    int id { get; set; }
    List<fruit> fruits { get; set; }
}
```

### The Desired (pseudo) Query

```
var bowls = repository.where(b => b.fruits.count > 1);
```

### The Question

**How do I do the above query using the NHibernate criteria API?**

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this (no subqueries, no detached criterias):

```
var bowls = repository.where(Restrictions.Gt("fruits.count", 1));
```

Is the above possible somehow?

cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible with detached criteria.

On the other hand, filtering by "count" is very easy using HQL:

```
from bowl where fruits.size > 1
```

Criteria API is not as powerful as HQL. Unfortunately, all this linq-style API's are based on criteria.

Comment: +1 thanks dude. yeah, the more I use the criteria api, the more sucky it is! I'm surprised the api doesn't just translate into hql first? if it did then the api should be able to handle "fuits.size" in the property parameter... I'll try this out, cheers

Comment: unfortunately, criteria does not translate to hql.

Comment: cool, cheers dude. It is strange that it doesn't isn't it..? anyways, cheers